# C# Masstransit using 30% CPU when idle

Tags: c#, masstransit

I've been searching for an answer for several days now to find out why my C# MassTransit configuration is using so much CPU when it is idle.

I found very few responses to other users asking this same question, and mostly they state "you must be doing something wrong".  Problem is, I've followed the examples on the MassTransit website and even done a bare bones project and still see it using 30+% cpu when it is just idle.

Is there something that can be done to make it use 0-10% when idle?  In our environment running a process that will consume 30+% cpu at idle is significant.

Here is an example of how I have MT configured in my dotnet 7 app:

```
.ConfigureServices((host, services) =>
{

IAgentInformation agentInformation = new AgentInformation(host.Configuration);

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
{
    x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

    var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

    x.AddConsumer<AgentConsumer>();
    x.AddSagaStateMachines(entryAssembly);
    x.AddSagas(entryAssembly);
    x.AddActivities(entryAssembly);

    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(agentInformation.ATLASServer, "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username(agentInformation.RabbitId);
            h.Password(agentInformation.Rabbit);
        });

        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
});
});
```

And when consuming:

```
public class AgentConsumer : IConsumer<ServerMessageContract>
```

{
readonly ILogger _logger;

```
public AgentConsumer(ILogger<AgentConsumer> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<ServerMessageContract> context)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Received Message: {Text}", context.Message.Payload == null ? "" : context.Message.Payload.ToString());
    TaskRunner.CommandsFromServer(context.Message);

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

}

And when publishing:

```
            var endpoint = await _bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri($"rabbitmq://{ServerAddress}/{SendQueue}"));
            await endpoint.Send(agentMessage, stoppingToken);
```

Pretty straight forward....

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't want to echo what you've heard elsewhere, but it's something on your end.

```text
CONTAINER ID   NAME                CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O         PIDS
09155c5ce2d1   outbox-postgres-1   0.12%     75.51MiB / 47.06GiB   0.16%     95.8kB / 107kB    47.3MB / 47.5MB   8
6ad4b6151e35   outbox-rabbitmq-1   0.51%     149.1MiB / 47.06GiB   0.31%     10.9kB / 8.23kB   57.3MB / 778kB    46
317dc978e517   outbox-api-1        0.55%     89.48MiB / 47.06GiB   0.19%     96.3kB / 89.8kB   34.9MB / 0B       29
8dda648a87ad   outbox-jaeger-1     0.05%     10.66MiB / 47.06GiB   0.02%     1.47kB / 0B       29.7MB / 0B       16
f01392265691   outbox-service-1    0.00%     67.85MiB / 47.06GiB   0.14%     21.8kB / 14.1kB   62.1MB / 0B       16
```

Both `outbox-api` and `outbox-service` are running MassTransit against RabbitMQ with a whole bunch of endpoints. As you can see, nearly idle.

This is from the [Sample-Outbox](https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Outbox) project.

Comment: I'm running it as a Windows Service.  I created a fresh bare bones app to see if it is something I am doing, and it seems that MT runs great until adding the Windows Service configuration.  After adding that the CPU usage moves to 30%.  Is there some best practice for running MT as a windows service?

Comment: Even more odd, the high CPU only presents when i compile the application into a binary.  In debug it seems to be sub 5% cpu usage...

Comment: ok, yep, something I'm doing is making a mess.  I just started from scratch one more time and this time added the windows service and MT starting with MT and it is sitting at 0% cpu at idle.  Now I need to one by one add things to find out where i'm breaking it.

Comment: Ugh, it is the windows service that is causing the spike.  I'm going to have to figure out why.  Thank you for the information you provided.